# NPDA which accepts all the strings of a's and b's that have equal number of a's and b's, but do not end up with an a

Tags: pushdown-automata

I have to design an NPDA(Non-Deterministic Push Down  Automata) for all the strings over
$\{a, b \}^*$, which have equal numbers of $a$'s and $b$'s but do not end up with an $a$.

I know how we should create an NPDA for the strings with an equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s, which its machine would be like this:
[image]

But I don't know how to add this condition to it, that it must not end up with an $a$.
My idea was to a union between $2$ languages for this question.

First, all the languages which have an equal number of $a$' and $b$'s, end up with an $a$.

Second, all the languages which have an equal number of $a$'s and $b$'s, end up with a $b$.
My main problem is working with my stack, and handling its contents on the edges.

How can I add this condition on the last symbol of an input?

Comment: Hint, an NPDA has states. One state means the last symbol was an $a$. Another state means the last symbol was a $b$.

Comment: If it sees an $a$, change its state to $q_a$. If it sees a $b$, to $q_b$.

Comment: You mean if the first symbol was $a$ go to $q_a$? Then if the input was $b$, we should pop from the stack, but how to determine the last symbol?@JohnL.

Comment: What @JohnL. is trying to say here is that when your NPDA is at state $q_a$, then you know that the current last symbol read is an $a$. So if no other symbol is read after then your NPDA will not accept, else your NPDA  will either read a $b$ and move to another state or stay at $q_a$ if it read an $a$ again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple mental model of a PDA or NPDA is **a finite state machine plus a stack**.

Both parts can be used to remember which kind has been the input taken by the automaton so far. The finite-state-machine part can remember bounded-many information. The stack can remember unbounded-many information (but for any particular moment, it is only readable/changeable at the very top).

When there is some information that cannot be remembered by the stack easily, **the finite-state-machine part can help remember**.

---

The transitions of the wanted NPDA can be as simple as the following.

# $q_1$ is the initial state. $Z$ denotes the bottom of the stack.
# When next input is $a$, the state becomes $q_a$. The subscript "${\,}_a$" in state "$q_a$" means the last input symbol was an $a$.
$q_1, a,Z\to q_a, aZ$
$q_1, a, a\to q_a, aa$
$q_a, a, a\to q_a, aa$
$q_1, a, b\to q_a, \lambda$
$q_a, a, b\to q_a, \lambda$

# When next input is $b$, the state becomes $q_1$. So $q_1$ implies the last input symbol was not an $a$.
$q_1, b,Z\to q_1, bZ$
$q_1, b, b\to q_1, bb$
$q_a, b, b\to q_1, bb$
$q_1, b, a\to q_1, \lambda$
$q_a, b, a\to q_1, \lambda$

# Only at state $q_1$, the NPDA may transition to accept.
$q_a, \lambda, Z\to q_f, Z$